# Why aren't the locators independently enabled/disabled?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, interface

I am wondering why the `Enabled` setting for the first locator (point1) overrides the `Enabled` setting for the second locator (point2).  Any ideas?

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{ {{Arrow[{{0, 0}, point1}]}}, {{Arrow[{{0, 0}, 
   point2}]}}},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-4, 8}, {-4, 8}}],
{{point1, {-1, 3}}, {-4, -4}, {8, 8}, {.1, .1}, Locator, Enabled -> False},
{{point2, {5, -2}}, {-3, -3}, {6, 6}, {.1, .1}, Locator, Enabled -> True}]
```

One of the locators should be enabled; the other should be disabled.  However, as the picture shows, they are both disabled.

I realize I could work around this by using `LocatorPane`, but I'm curious why this doesn't work for individual locators.  Am I overlooking something or is this a bug?

[image: locators]

Comment: I assume all locators are swept together internally and the first `Enabled` encountered determines the state of all.  There is some hint (it's not precisely your situation) about the internal difficulties involved in combining multiple locators in the documentation: "*Due to internal limitations, it is not possible to combine individual Locator variables with a variable that is a list of multiple Locator variables: you can have only one multipoint Locator variable in a Manipulate.*"

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Can you include a link? My last question would also benefit from it

Comment: @belisarius It's slightly below http://wolfram.com/xid/0fz3xp8d3e93ro (the `Locator` section, between In[36] and In[37]).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, going to update my question

Comment: @Sjoerd: I see. But neither of the locators I'm using is multipoint.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I wrote that this does not correspond exactly to your situation. I assume that all individual `Locator` variables are internally merged into a single multipoint list and that could be the reason that another multipoint list is not welcome here. If there is one internal point list then I'd guess there is also only one internal `Enabled` state. But this is all guesswork based on the above mentioned doc snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As surmised by @Sjoerd in the question's comments, `Manipulate` combines all locators into a single `LocatorPaneBox`.  We can see this if we inspect the boxes generated by the `Manipulate` expression:

```
PaneBox[PanelBox[DynamicWrapperBox[PaneSelectorBox[{True->GridBox[{{
...
LocatorPaneBox[
  Dynamic[{$CellContext`point1$$,$CellContext`point2$$}],
  ...
  Enabled->False,Enabled->True]
...
FrameMargins->{{5,5},{5,5}}],ImageMargins->0,BaselinePosition->Automatic]
```

This excerpted snippet shows us two things.  First, we can see the single `LocatorPaneBox` that references both points.  Second, we can see that the `Enabled` option is specified twice.  As usual, the first instance takes precedence over the second with the result that both locators are disabled.  This second point feels like a bug.

To work around this problem is tricky.  We could try to use an explicit `LocatorPane`, but that does not allow us to specify independent regions or enablement states for each locator.  If we try to use two `LocatorPane` expressions, we run into problems when the outer pane is disabled -- events do not get sent down to the inner pane.  It is possible to work around this using elaborate `EventHandler` interactions, but it is not pretty.  I suspect that these problems are what led to the present restrictions in the `Manipulate` implementation.

In this particular case, a simpler solution is to abandon `LocatorPane` altogether and to include explicit `Locator` directives instead:

```
clip[pt:{x_, y_}, {xMin_, yMin_}, {xMax_, yMax_}, {xStep_, yStep_}] :=
  {Round[Clip[x, {xMin, xMax}], xStep], Round[Clip[y, {yMin, yMax}], yStep]}

Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    { Arrow[{{0, 0}, point1}]
    , Arrow[{{0, 0}, point2}]
    , Locator[Dynamic[point1,(point1=clip[#, {-4, -4}, {8, 8}, {.1, .1}])&], Enabled->False]
    , Locator[Dynamic[point2,(point2=clip[#, {-3, -3}, {6, 6}, {.1, .1}])&], Enabled->True]
    }
  , Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-4, 8}, {-4, 8}}
  ]
, {{point1, {-1, 3}}, None}
, {{point2, {5, -2}}, None}
]
```

Unfortunately, this means that we must implement the locator region constraints ourselves since `Locator` does not offer that service (`LocatorRegion` only provides crude clipping).  However, this is easier than the event-handling gymnastics that would otherwise be required for `LocatorPane`.

Comment: Very nice! Using this method, and checkboxes, it is also possible to control both the Enabled state and visibility (i.e Appearance) of each locator independently.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a possible workaround to overcome the issue (WReach has nicely debunked it) by simulating a `Manipulate` interface. As always, start by writing a `DynamicModule` object that is then wrapped in a dummy `Manipulate` wrapper:

```
Manipulate@DynamicModule[{point1 = {-1, 3}, point2 = {5, -2}},
  Graphics[{
    Dynamic@Arrow[{{0, 0}, point1}],
    Dynamic@Arrow[{{0, 0}, point2}],
    Locator[Dynamic[point1, (point1 = Clip[#, {-4, 8}]) &], Enabled -> False],
    Locator[Dynamic[point2, (point2 = Clip[#, {-3, 6}]) &], Enabled -> True]
    }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-4, 8}, {-4, 8}}]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What advantages are gained by using `Dynamic Module`?  Also, in what sense is `Manipulate` being used as a dummy wrapper. Do you mean that no interactive functionality is actually required? (Actually, in the full implementation, there are 8 or so controls that are needed.  Most are checkboxes, including those to Enable/Disable the locators individually.)

Comment: @David The `DynamicModule` works perfectly without the `Manipulate`. It is dynamic in itself and can hold any number of `Locator`s or `LocatorPane`s, so the `Manipulate` is only there to provide 1) the familiar paneled look-and-feel (e.g. the + button in the top right), and 2) the somewhat necessary wrapper for [deploying to CDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3964/89).