# Clicking to add/remove a Locator

Tags: manipulate, locator

I would like to add a `Locator` to a figure displayed by `Manipulate` when I click inside the figure, at the location where I click, and to have this trigger an update of the figure. I would also like to have clicking on an existing `Locator` remove it, and dragging a locator reposition it (again, redrawing the figure in response in each case).

For (a silly) example, I would like clicking anywhere in the region displayed by

```
With[{locs = {}}, 
 Manipulate[Graphics[Text[locs, {0, 0}], PlotRange -> 2],
  {{q, {1, 1}}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> Graphics[{Green, Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> 10]},
  {{p, locs}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, .1]}, ImageSize -> 10]}]]
```

to add the corresponding `Point` to `locs`, and for clicking on any `p` `Locator` to remove it from `locs`, with the text, updating accordingly in response to additions, deletions or repositionings of a `Locator`.

To make things hard, I have another locator `q` that needs to coexist with the one to which I would like to add/remove; and `p` and `q` have different appearances.

Comment: Check the docs for [LocatorAutoCreate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorAutoCreate.html).

Comment: @kguler: Good suggestion, but I actually have *another* locator in the `Manipulate` that seems to "get in the way": nothing happens when I click, even with `LocatorAutoCreate -> All`.

Comment: Seen this [Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14015/125)?

Comment: @kguler: I've asked to have this reopened. The linked question does not, in fact, answer this one: how do I add (remove) `Locator`s by clicking on the location where I want the locator (of the locator I want to remove)? I should have thought that (and not adding at random locations, or removing the last-added `Locator`) was implicit.

Comment: voted to reopen.

Comment: @kguler: Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach the overall goal of the program in a different way that avoids the limitations* of `Manipulate`.  I would store a list of all the locators in one variable, with the permanent locator(s) at the beginning of the list.  The transient locators can be added and removed with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+click.  The permanent locators are maintained by the option of the form `LocatorAutoCreate -> min`, where `min` is the number of permanent locators.

Using `With` to assign symbols to represent the parts of the list `locs` of locators seems slightly inelegant, but overall the approach has the advantage of being simple.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{q = locs[[1]], p = Drop[locs, 1]}, 
  Graphics[Text[locs, {0, 0}], PlotRange -> 2]
  ],
 {{locs, {{1, 1}}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> 1}
 ]
```

---

**Limitation:*
When several `Locator` controls, `p`, `q`, ..., appear in a `Manipulate`, a `LocatorPane` is created of the form

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p, q, ...}], ...]
```

The option `LocatorAutoCreate` can be passed to the `LocatorPane`; however, it does not work because the length of the list `{p, q, ...}` cannot be changed.

---

**Update: Appearance**

The appearance of the locators may be controlled in two ways.  The documented, and hence common, solution is to use invisible locators and insert graphics primitives into the `Graphics`:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{q = locs[[1]], p = Drop[locs, 1]}, 
  Graphics[{
    Text[locs, {0, 0}],
    Locator[q], {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p]},
   PlotRange -> 2]
  ],
 {{locs, {{1, 1}}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> 1}
 ]
```

Another way is to use the option setting

```
Appearance -> {Automatic, Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]}
```

The last specification is repeated when there are more than two locators, a behavior that I could not find documented.

Comment: I've been balking at the complex solutions and had settled on exactly this as a possible approach.

Comment: It looks like I'm stuck with a single `Appearance` with this approach. Is that correct? The first and rest need to look different.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No, you can set `Appearance -> None` and use `Locator[q]`, `{Red, Point[p]}` inside the graphics.  You might be able to use a different setting for appearance, but I'm not where I can check at this time.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It also turns out that you can use another setting for `Appearance`.  See update. :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the follow up. I tired that earlier and couldn't get it to work; I must have mistyped.

Answer (score 3):

As kguler points out, this question appears to have be treated previously [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14015/3066). However, jVincent's answer only treats the case of adding additional locators. Here is an example that where locators can be both added and deleted.

```
SetAttributes[canDelete, HoldFirst]
canDelete[locatorGroup_Symbol] :=
  Switch[locatorGroup,
    {}, False,
    {_}, Unevaluated@locatorGroup = {}; False,
    {__}, Unevaluated@locatorGroup = Most[locatorGroup]; True]

DynamicModule[{black = {}, red = {}, deleteQ},
  deleteQ["black"] = False;
  deleteQ["red"] = False; 
  Grid[{
    {Framed[
       Graphics[{
         Dynamic[
           With[{i = #}, Locator[Dynamic[black[[i]]], Style[\[FilledSquare], Black]]] &
             /@ Range@Length@black], 
         Dynamic[
           With[{i = #}, Locator[Dynamic[red[[i]]], Style[\[FilledCircle], Red]]] &
             /@ Range@Length@red]},
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]], 
    SpanFromLeft}, 
   {Button["Add Black", AppendTo[black, RandomReal[1, 2]]; deleteQ["black"] = True], 
    Button["Add Red", AppendTo[red, RandomReal[1, 2]]; deleteQ["red"] = True]},
   {Dynamic[Button["Delete Black", deleteQ["black"] = canDelete[black], 
              Enabled -> deleteQ["black"]]],
    Dynamic[Button["Delete Red", deleteQ["red"] = canDelete[red], 
              Enabled -> deleteQ["red"]]]}}]]
```

[image: two-locator-groups]

Comment: Note that this does not really answer the question, since the whole point of adding locators is that they appears where I click, not in some `Random` location (likewise for removing). I would have thought this was implicit.