# How do I keep a random value associated with a locator point as points are added?

Tags: manipulate, random, locator

I have a `Manipulate` to which I am adding and removing `Locator` points ([one of which is different](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45711/37) from the others, though that is only context for this question):

```
lastP = {}; states = {};
setState[p_] := RandomReal[Abs[p[[1]]]];
Manipulate[With[{q = locs[[1]], p = Drop[locs, 1]},
  If[Length[lastP] < Length[p], states = Append[states, setState[p[[-1]]]]];
  If[Length[lastP] > Length[p], states = states[[Flatten[Position[lastP, #] & /@ p]]]];
  lastP = p;
  Graphics[{
    Text[TableForm[MapThread[List, {p, states}]], {0, 0}], 
    Red, Table[Circle[q, i/30], {i, 3}], 
    Blue, Point[#] & /@ p}, PlotRange -> 2]],
 Row[{
   Button["Clear", {locs = {locs[[1]]}}, ImageSize -> 100, 
    Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}],
   Button["Recalc", states = setState[#] & /@ Drop[locs, 1], 
    ImageSize -> 100, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}]
   }], {{locs, {{1, 1}}}, Locator, Appearance -> None, 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> 1}]
```

I need to associate with each of the `Locator` points in `p` a random value (according to some specified PDF that is a function of the point's coordinates, here using `setState` as an example) that is calculated and associated with the point *only when it is added or moved*, but not when other points are added or moved. I would also like to have access to the association between this value and the point, so that I can adjust the display of each point according to that associated value (e.g. making those with values less than some threshold one color and those greater another).

How can I (ideally without giving up on `Manipulate`) achieve this "stable" association of calculated values with `Locator` points? I've played with various approaches for hours, and, with help, I've gotten as far as getting what I want for adding and removing; but I expect there's some simpler approach that I'm missing, and I haven't managed to get *moving* (i.e., updates to the calculated value associated with a point) working.

Comment: @Kuba: I can't figure out how to get the `setState` when I *move* (drag) an existing point.

Comment: @Kuba: No idea. That was autocorrect's idea: "get the" should be "recompute".

Comment: Ok :P so probably you should correct th sentence "only when it is added or moved, but not when other points are added or moved."